# How do I conditionally create and use parent classes in Python 3

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I am building an API that I would like to use in applications using pyqt and other guis. 
If a programmer is using a gui other that Qt I don't want her to have to import pyqt etc.
My problem is that I use a task to subscribe to messages and pass them through to the main task.
I accomplish this by passing a parameter (qt) which is either True or False depending on what gui we are implementing.
I then create a class that generates a SubscriberParent class of either a QtCore.QThread or a Thread. The ultimate SubscriberThread
is of type SubscriberThreadParent.
The main thread either polls the interTaskQueue or uses Qt's signals and slots to process the message.

```
    class Gui(object):
        def __init__(self, qt):
          if qt:
            from PyQt5 import QtCore
            from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal

            class SubScriberThreadParent(QtCore.QThread):
                def __init__(self):
                    QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
          else:
                from threading import Thread

          class SubScriberThreadParent(Thread):
                def __init__(self):
                    Thread.__init__(self)


    class SubscriberThread(Gui.SubScriberThreadParent):


        def __init__(self, qt, dsParam, SubScriberThreadParent):

          if qt:
              from PyQt5 import QtCore
              from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal
              pubIn = pyqtSignal(str, str)


          SubScriberThreadParent.__init__(self)

          self.interTaskQueue = dsParam.interTaskQueue
          .
          .
          .
          .


        #
        # Pass the message on to the main application
        #

        def alertMainApp(self, bodyTuple):

          if self.qt:
            btz = '{0}'.format(bodyTuple)
            self.pubIn.emit(btz)
            LOGGER.info("Emitted Alert ")
          else:
            if self.interTaskQueue != None:
              self.interTaskQueue.put(bodyTuple)  # Pass it to the main thread
              LOGGER.info("Queued Alert.")
            else:
              LOGGER.error("No Inter-task data transfer method available to the subscriber task!")
```

The error I get with this approach is: "AttributeError: type object 'Gui' has no attribute 'SubScriberThreadParent'"

How can I make this work?

I also would like to know the scope of the conditional imports.

Answer (score 1):

In order for one class to inherit from `Gui.SubScriberThreadParent` you will have to have created an instance of `Gui` and assigned something to a class variable.

Consider this code:

```
class Gui:
    def __init__(self, qt):
        if qt:
            class Foo:
                att = 'Foo'
            Gui.Parent = Foo
        else:
            class Bar:
                att = 'Bar'
            Gui.Parent = Bar

def makeThread():
    class Thread(Gui.Parent):
        def __init__(self):
            self.att = Gui.Parent.att
    return Thread()

def main():
    Gui(False)
    t = makeThread()
    print(t.att)

main()
```

Output:

With `Gui(False)` as above, the output is:

```
Bar
```

When changed to `Gui(True)`, the output is:

```
Foo
```

Comment: Your approach seems to be working but I am having a rough time initializing the Parent.

Comment: Do you know how to initialize parent classes from the subclass?

Comment: Which parent do you mean? It looks like you are initializing the thread parents ok.

Comment: def makeSubscriber(self, dsParam, applicationUser, archiver, qt):

        pass

        class SubscriberThread(self.Parent):

            # super.__init__(self.Parent)
            from PyQt5 import QtCore
            QtCore.QThread.__init__(self.Parent)


I haven't tried initializing the simple Thread class yet.

Comment: To clarify:
             QtCore.QThread.__init__(self) requires self as a parameter but that is Gui so I moved the initialization of the super class into the child which is in the makeSubscriber method within the Gui class. I then use QtCore.QThread.__init__(self.Parent) which gives me: "TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'sip.simplewrapper' object but received a 'sip.wrappertype' "

I haven't tried initializing the simple Thread class yet.

Comment: I think you would be better off just defining the exact classes that you need first to make sure they work and later on you could employ a Factory Pattern to make the right ones at runtime. However, all of that is another question - which you could ask on stackoverflow.